# Diagnosing why external NVMe keeps disconnecting

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, macos

I recently purchased a 4 TB TeamGroup MP34 NVMe drive that I am using with an NVMe enclosure as an external drive on my MacBook Pro.

I was copying files from another 4 TB drive onto it. The first terabyte or so completed without issues, before I paused it to continue it at a later time. Later I continued the copying procedure. However, this time around, the MP34 drive kept on disconnecting and reconnecting every couple of minutes, causing the copying to fail.

I thought it was perhaps due to the high temperatures of the NVMe since the external enclosure was quite hot (note: this apparently wasn't an issue for the first TB of data written, so I *doubt* it's the actual issue).

I decided to put the drive outside, where the temperatures are below freezing. This did not help—the drive kept disconnecting over and over again.

Is there any way for me to troubleshoot why the drive keeps disconnecting? Are there any logs that I can view?

Comment: How is the external drive connected? Have you checked all the connections are physically secure? Both the cabling and the NVMe drive itself in its socket in the enclosure?